# Problema con DataTables - Invalid JSON response

Tags: php, javascript, datatables

Estoy obteniendo el siguiente error, pero solo en determinadas páginas de la DataTable. Por ejemplo, en la página 1 y 2, no hay problemas, pero cuando paso a la 3, salta este error:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Me estoy basando en el código de ejemplo oficial de [DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)

Tengo todo tal cual al ejemplo...

**index.html**

```
...
<table id='example' class='display' style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><b>Nombre y Apellido</b></th>
            <th><b>Fecha Nac.</b></th>
            <th><b>Tel&eacute;fono</b></th>
            <th><b>E-mail</b></th>
            <th><b>Localidad</b></th>
            <th><b>Clase/s</b></th>
            <th><b>Fecha vto. pago</b></th>
            <th><b>Asd</b></th>
            <th><b>+</b></th>
            <th><b>-</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th><b>Nombre y Apellido</b></th>
            <th><b>Fecha Nac.</b></th>
            <th><b>Tel&eacute;fono</b></th>
            <th><b>E-mail</b></th>
            <th><b>Localidad</b></th>
            <th><b>Clase/s</b></th>
            <th><b>Fecha vto. pago</b></th>
            <th><b>Asd</b></th>
            <th><b>+</b></th>
            <th><b>-</b></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
...
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../updListaT.php"
    } );
} );
```

**server-side script (updListaT.php)**

```
<?php
    require_once 'class/redirNoLog.php';


    // DB table to use
    $table = 'tramite';

    // Table's primary key
    $primaryKey = 'idT';

    // Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
    // The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
    // parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
    // indexes
    $columns = array(
        array( 'db' => 'fecha_ingreso', 'dt' => 0 ),
        array( 'db' => 'nombre', 'dt' => 1 ),
        array( 'db' => 'direccion', 'dt' => 2 ),
        array( 'db' => 'localidad', 'dt' => 3 ),
        array( 'db' => 'tel', 'dt' => 4 ),
        array( 'db' => 'fecha_nac', 'dt' => 5 ),
        array( 'db' => 'fecha_vto', 'dt' => 6 ),
        array( 'db' => 'fecha_ult_pago', 'dt' => 7 ),
        array( 'db' => 'baja', 'dt' => 8 ),
        array( 'db' => 'suspendido', 'dt' => 9 )
    );

    // SQL server connection information
    $sql_details = array(
        'user' => 'admin',
        'pass' => 'db_pass',
        'db'   => 'nkru',
        'host' => 'localhost'
    );


    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
     * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
     */

    require('class/ssp.class.php');


    echo json_encode(SSP::simple($_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);




?>
```

Aquí el **JSON de la página 1** (que no da error)

```
  {
      "draw": 1,
      "recordsTotal": 1254,
      "recordsFiltered": 1254,
      "data": [
          ["0000-00-00", "Esteban Quito", "est@asd.com", "Santa Fe", "34921234593", "1990-11-07", "2018-05-01", "2018-04-10", "0", "0"],
          ["0000-00-00", "Usr prueba", "aggg@sss.com", "Santa Fe", "3434231351", "2000-12-12", "1975-09-03", "2018-04-12", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-03-29", "Usuario prueba", "aaeee@gasdf.com", "Santa Fe", "3345264349", "1997-05-13", "2019-09-10", "2019-05-21", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-03-29", "Prueba asd", "asdasd@prrrrrb.com", "Santa Fe", "34342234522", "2018-03-12", "2018-08-28", "2019-04-30", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-04-03", "prueba para reporte", "asdasd@prbrep.com", "Rafaela", "34921234567", "2018-04-10", "2018-06-03", "2019-04-30", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-04-13", "asdasdasd", "asdasdasa@asdasda.com", "Santa Fe", "3492642314", "2018-04-14", "2020-05-03", "2019-05-21", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-04-23", "PRUEBA01", "prb01@host.com", "Santa Fe", "3492111111", "1991-11-11", "2018-04-03", "0000-00-00", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-04-23", "PRUEBA02", "prb02@host.com", "Santa Fe", "3492222222", "1992-12-12", "2018-04-03", "0000-00-00", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-04-23", "PRUEBA01", "prb01@host.com", "Santa Fe", "3492111111", "1991-11-11", "2018-04-23", "0000-00-00", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-04-23", "PRUEBA02", "prb02@host.com", "Santa Fe", "3423452456", "1992-12-12", "2019-04-23", "2019-05-21", "0", "0"]
      ]
  }
```

Y aquí el **JSON de la página 3** (que sí da el error mencionado al inicio)

```
{
      "draw": 1,
      "recordsTotal": 1254,
      "recordsFiltered": 1254,
      "data": [
          ["2018-03-29", "Prueba asd", "seeed@prrrrrb.com", "Santa Fe", "3532222222", "2018-03-12", "2018-08-28", "2019-04-30", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-04-03", "prueba para reporte", "efeasd@prbrep.com", "Santa Fe", "34921234567", "2018-04-10", "2018-06-03", "2019-04-30", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-04-13", "eeeeeddd", "gsdfff@ssdggg.com", "Santa Fe", "4324642314", "2018-04-14", "2020-05-03", "2019-05-21", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-04-23", "PRUEBA01", "prb01@host.com", "Santa Fe", "1153111111", "1991-11-11", "2018-04-03", "0000-00-00", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-04-23", "PRUEBA02", "prb02@host.com", "Santa Fe", "3643222222", "1992-12-12", "2018-04-03", "0000-00-00", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-04-23", "PRUEBA01", "prb01@host.com", "Santa Fe", "3495111111", "1991-11-11", "2018-04-23", "0000-00-00", "0", "0"],
          ["2018-04-23", "PRUEBA02", "prb02@host.com", "Santa Fe", "3454123456", "1992-12-12", "2019-04-23", "2019-05-21", "0", "0"],
          ["2019-04-30", "Juan Pérez", "jperez@host.com", "Santa Fe", "3464111111", "1995-04-20", "2019-04-01", "0000-00-00", "0", "0"],
          ["2019-06-13", "Cliente Uno", "rsgdf@ssssre.com", "Santa Fe", "3415324353", "1997-05-13", "2019-06-05", "0000-00-00", "0", "0"],
          ["2019-06-13", "Cliente Dos", "", "Sta fe", "", "0000-00-00", "2019-06-05", "0000-00-00", "0", "0"]
      ]
  }
```

Cabe mencionar que ambos JSON los validé con [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) y están correctos.

Si alguien podría ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me autorespondo para que quede la pregunta resuelta.

El problema estaba con las páginas que contenían filas con datos con acentos y/o ñ...
Es cuestión de guardar correctamente los caracteres en la base de datos para que se solucione el problema.